# Need help scraping an NHL statistics table with lxml and xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am new to python(using python3.6), I am learning it mainly to be able to build a scraper for this page
http://www.nhl.com/stats/player?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=skatersummary&pos=S&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20162017&seasonTo=20162017&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,goals,assists

I have tried many things, I originally wanted to try with xpath but after failing, I decide to try with BeautifulSoup4 and I am getting this error

```
    for row in soup('table', {'class': 'stat-table'})[0].tbody('tr'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

from this code

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.nhl.com/stats/player?aggregate=0&gameType=2&report=skatersummary&pos=S&reportType=season&seasonFrom=20162017&seasonTo=20162017&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,goals,assists'),"lxml")

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'stat-table'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print(tds[0].string, tds[1].string)
```

Comment: a `table` with `class="stat-table"` doesn't exist on that request. That information comes dynamically. Check for "javascript rendering".

Comment: yes, when I realised it was javascript, I knew i needed a different method. The answer by wu4m4n works perfectly but I am also going to research "javascript rendering" to learn more. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this works, you have to find the correct url who make the requests to the internal API.

To get the url you have to use the web console of google chrome.

1) open the console and make click in "Network"

[image]

2) then refresh the website and you will see all the requests from this page.

[image]

3) then you have to filter by "XHR" , and there you go!

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import lxml.html
from pprint import pprint 
from sys import exit
import json
import csv

url = 'http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/grouped/skaters/basic/season/skatersummary?cayenneExp=seasonId=20162017 and gameTypeId=2&factCayenneExp=gamesPlayed>=1&sort=[{"property":"points","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"goals","direction":"DESC"},{"property":"assists","direction":"DESC"}]'
resp = requests.get(url).text
resp = json.loads(resp)

pprint(resp['data'])
```

Comment: and how exactly do I get the correct URL? Sorry, I am new to this. Also, Thank you

Comment: For some reason, the table won't reload when i reload the page in google chrome. But, it worked when I used Safari. Thanks again, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: I managed to make it work in google chrome as well! I did a restore to defaults in the dev tools settings. Must have been something I changed in the past without knowing.

Comment: How about this page https://www.capfriendly.com/players/shea-weber? The same thing doesn't seem to work. at least not for all the tables.

Comment: This code worked for the other tables on the capfriendly.com page except the last(ajax) one.                                                                                                        import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.capfriendly.com/players/shea-weber'),"lxml")

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'cntrct'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print(tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[2].string, tds[3].string, tds[4].string, tds[5].string, tds[6].string, tds[7].string)

Comment: @wu4m4n, would you mind explaining how you knew to look/filter for XHR?

Comment: @Charlie because I always check the source code to see if they use ajax .